# Any way to show an image with an Alert

Tags: iphone

All,

I am doing an app, where after selecting 5 images a pop should appear saying its done, and having a OK button, after clicking OK it will come to its original view.

How can I do that, can I show an image with the alert view.

Please help me.

Many Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this:

```
UIAlertView *successAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220, 10, 40, 40)];

    NSString *path = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"]];
    UIImage *bkgImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [imageView setImage:bkgImg];
    [bkgImg release];
    [path release];

    [successAlert addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];

    [successAlert show];
    [successAlert release];
```

I *think* that this should work. Don't know if it'll pass apple's review though.

Comment: Yeah its working fine, many thanks,but is there any way to set the frame size for the Alert View, like I want to show an alert covering whole screen, again Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer Aurum's post to set an image inside your alertview.

To cover the whole screen you need to customize your alertview.

For this you can refer to this [Post](http://iphonedevcentral.blogspot.com/2010/08/custom-alert-views.html)